# Node Firebase stuck in module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const User = require("./config");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', async(req,res) => {
  const snapshot = await User.get();
  const list = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
  res.send(list);
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("Server running at port 4000")
})
```

**config.js**

```
const firebase = require("firebase");

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "",
authDomain: "",
 projectId: "",
 storageBucket: "",
 messagingSenderId: "",
 appId: "",
 measurementId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();
const User = db.collection("Users");

module.exports = User;
```

I am trying to create a project connecting Firebase to Node.js but I encountered a problem that `Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined` when I run `nodemon index.js`. Can anyone help solve the above problem?

I am expecting the app runs normally after using `module.exports` but the app crashed even I followed thoroughly the documentation

Comment: You need to use Firebase Admin from Node.js. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#node.js (make sure you select Node.js for the code examples)

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebase admin according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#node.js_1).
The Cloud Firestore SDK is initialized in different way in nodeJs.